# How to publish Flutter app to Playstore with fastla

Tags: android, flutter, fastlane

I have successfully setup fastlane to upload a flutter application to the Android Play Store, but it did not make it available to my internal testers. I am thinking I am missing an option to upload_to_play_store. Here is my lane definition:

```
 desc "Submit a new Internal Build"
  lane :internal do
    upload_to_play_store(
      track: 'internal',
      release_status: 'draft',
      aab: "../build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab"
    )
  end
```